# how to extend ctools functions in my own js file?

Tags: javascript, chaos-tool-suite

I am trying to extend the ctools model functions in my JavaScript file but not getting the exact way.

In ctool model.js contains `modalContentClose = function(){close(); return false;};` which I want to override in my JavaScript file to add more functionality.

I have tried to use the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
function extends modalContentClose() {
  // Some alert here.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript doesn't allow extending a function with another one. If you want to extend `modalContentClose()` you just redefine it in your JavaScript file that is included after the JavaScript used by ctools.module.

```
modalContentClose = function() {
  // Add your own code.
  close();
  return false;
};
```

Your version of `modalContentClose()` cannot refer the previous `modalContentClose()`, if you don't save it in a new variable, as with the following code.

```
originalContentClose = modalContentClose;

modalContentClose = function() {
  // Add your own code.
  originalContentClose();
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if you don't save it in a new variable, as with the following code."?

Comment: Once JavaScript executes, `modalContentClose = function() { /* code */};` the previous value of `modalContentClose` is not anymore available. It is like when you use `foo = 'bar'; foo = 'another bar';`. JavaScript can give you the actual value of `foo`, but it cannot give you the previous value, if you don't save it in a new variable.

Comment: I see, I guess your answer is more generic javascript solution than specific to this function modalContentClose. In ctools module this function "modalContentClose" is an inner function, so I don't think you can override it in any way. Thanks